# Positive input terminal - Basic Circuit Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

I am trying to do some basic analysis over some circuits, however, I am unsure how to deal with the non-inverting input. I already found Vin/20 and -Vout/100 based on the other 2 resistors, I am stuck on the third one. We were using 0 for V- so I was guessing V+ would be 1, but I could not find any information on the matter. Assume ideal op amps

[image]

Comment: Do you know what the relationship between V+ and V- should be for an Op-Amp with negative feedback?

Comment: I do not know @jramsay42

Comment: You might want to look up the "golden rules" for Op-Amp analysis then

Answer (score 1):

To figure it out, consider

- What's the current going in to an input pin of an ideal op-amp?
- Therefore, according to Ohm's law, what's the voltage across that resistor?

Stop and work this out, then continue reading...

> The reason that resistor is there is because real op-amps aren't ideal. There will be a small current in or out of the input pin. To minimize the error caused by this current, you want an equal effective resistance connected to each of the input pins. So really the resistor value should be 20 || 100 = 16 or 17 kohms, not 10 kohms.